# join some table twice in Django ORM

Tags: django

I have two models

```
class Customer(AbstractBaseModel):    
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_column='uuid')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)

class CustomerAddress(AbstractBaseModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_column='uuid')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='addresses', db_column='customer_uuid')
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=[('shipping', 'shipping'), ('billing', 'billing')])
```

User can filter customers using two fields: `billing_country` and `shipping_country`, they can fill either one or both fields. If user fills both fields, I have to join to `CustomerAddress` table twice. I do this in raw SQL like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN address shipping_address ON shipping_address.customer_uuid = c.uuid AND shipping_address.type = 'shipping'
LEFT OUTER JOIN address billing_address ON billing_address.customer_uuid = c.uuid AND billing_address.type = 'billing'
```

and append WHERE clauses if user uses filters like this:

```
# billing_country and shipping_country are sanitized at this point
filters = []
if billing_country:
    filters.append(f"billing_address.country_code = '{billing_country}'")
if shipping_country:
    filters.append(f"shipping_address.country_code = '{shipping_country}'")
where_part = 'WHERE ' + ' AND '.join(filters)
```

How can I do this using Django ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [FilteredRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects):

```
qs = Customer.objects.annotate(
    shipping_address=FilteredRelation('address', condition=Q(address.type='shipping')),
    billing_address=FilteredRelation('address', condition=Q(address.type='billing'))
)
```

`WHERE` parts are appended like this:

```
if billing_country:
    qs.filter(billing_address__country_code__iexact=billing_country)
```